# Printing data of datatable with itextsharp and c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

because through this code I see only the first record in print
I checked in debug mode but the variables are assigned regularly .. do not go out .. arrg ... thanks for any response

this is the function that retrieve data

```
//Recupero dati cliente
DataTable GetCliItems()
{
   try
   {
       con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;User Id=root;password=cassano;database=cedas";
       //con.Open();

       //query per la visualizzazione di tutti i clienti
       string query = "select nome, cognome, indirizzo, telefono, cellulare, referente, note from clienti where rif_agente ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
       //adapter per eseguire la query
       adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
       DataSet DS = new DataSet();

       //restituisce il risultato della query nel dataset
       adapter.Fill(DS);

       return DS.Tables[0];
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Errore durante il recupero delle informazioni.\n\n" + ex.Message, "Errore", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
   finally { con.Close(); }

   return null;
}
```

and this is the iTextSharp print

```
for (int i = 0; i < DTCliAg.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string nome = DTCliAg.Rows[i]["nome"].ToString();
    string cognome = DTCliAg.Rows[i]["cognome"].ToString();
    string indirizzo = DTCliAg.Rows[i]["indirizzo"].ToString();
    string telefono = DTCliAg.Rows[i]["telefono"].ToString();
    string cellulare = DTCliAg.Rows[i]["cellulare"].ToString();
    string referente = DTCliAg.Rows[i]["referente"].ToString();
    string note = DTCliAg.Rows[i]["note"].ToString();

    PdfPCell[] cellsCli = new PdfPCell[] { new PdfPCell(new Phrase(nome, fontStampaTable)),
                                           new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cognome, fontStampaTable)),
                                           new PdfPCell(new Phrase(indirizzo, fontStampaTable)),
                                           new PdfPCell(new Phrase(telefono, fontStampaTable)),
                                           new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellulare, fontStampaTable)),
                                           new PdfPCell(new Phrase(referente, fontStampaTable)),
                                           new PdfPCell(new Phrase(note, fontStampaTable))};

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
       cellsCli[j].HorizontalAlignment = 0;
       cellsCli[j].PaddingBottom = 3f;
       cellsCli[j].Border = 0;
    }

    PdfPRow rowCli = new PdfPRow(cellsCli);
    tabellaCliente.Rows.Add(rowCli);
```

Comment: Can you show where tabellaCliente is being used?

Comment: //Costruzione della tabella con i valori riga tramite array di celle
                        PdfPTable tabellaCliente = new PdfPTable(7);
                        tabellaCliente.WidthPercentage = 100;

Comment: I print only the first line and it seems ok .... for the second I have always old values

Comment: how many rows and columns in your pdfptable?

Comment: columns are 7...the rows depending by select statement that return in dataTable..

Comment: this code is working proper in my system.and one thing which iTextSharp version are you using?

Comment: You're not supposed to use the `PdfPRow` class directly; use `table.AddCell()` instead!

Comment: thank's bruno...but i solved with

Comment: PdfPTable tabellaCliente = new PdfPTable(7);
tabellaCliente.WidthPercentage = 100; in for loop...

Comment: thx manish for your reply